# Delete html with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made code to generate html rows.

How do I delete them now?? I don't have a random generated id.

```js
$('#addEnv').click(function() {
  $('#envVariablesDiv').append('<div class="col-sm-5 top10"><div class="input-group"><label class="input-group-addon">Name</label><input id="envName" class="form-control" name="envName" type="text" placeholder="e.g. name1" /></div></div>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-5 top10"><div class="input-group"><label class="input-group-addon">Variable</label><input class="form-control" id="envVar" type="text" name="envVar" placeholder="e.g. var1" /></div></div><div class="col-sm-2 top10"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-trash">Delete</span></button></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addEnv">Add</button>
<div id="envVariablesDiv">

</div>
```

Comment: Just add a container div with some class for all the new child element added, and on delete.. removed that container div in that `this` scope.

Comment: but i can't use id for the button.

Comment: You don't need to; use the class that's already on the button

Comment: `$(this).remove();` doesnt work. help

Comment: i have a working example why can't you help me on this? :/